# PostGIS rows are being inserted as hexadecimal WKT inside Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, postgis, postgresql-9.4, pgx

[image]As seen in the following function, I am trying to insert rows into the `building` table. Everything works except that instead of being saved as normal text, the coordinate is saved as WKB (as shown in the screenshot and sample).

```
func (db Database) SaveBuildings(buildings overpass.Result) error {
    tx, err := db.pool.Begin(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback(context.Background())
    for _, building := range buildings.Nodes {
        _, err = tx.Exec(context.Background(), `INSERT INTO building (coordinate, type, variation) VALUES(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2),4326), $3, $4)`, building.Lon, building.Lat, "industrial", "brick")
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = tx.Commit(context.Background())
    return err
}
```

`Building` table sample

```
uuid                                |coordinate                                        |type      |variation|
------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|----------|---------|
dff2f9a3-03f1-477c-8b3e-9c6708d97519|0101000020E610000028637C98BDE63B4092301D84CAE04740|industrial|brick    |
7b6b619a-8c0f-4a3d-b098-d878a2b1d152|0101000020E6100000EFE2FDB8FDE43B4085AC133C2AE04740|industrial|brick    |
efd68a88-a349-4f1b-9406-23920031701f|0101000020E6100000D7C3F24295E53B40A538FD8F02E04740|industrial|brick    |
3b9bfc69-9dbc-42f5-a80d-615b972da3a2|0101000020E610000085E39E5335EA3B40B1FD648C0FE14740|industrial|brick    |
19e798d9-5ce7-47e4-aea0-0eb039805269|0101000020E6100000CD48731A58E73B40A76384A6DBDF4740|industrial|brick    |
c99ab27c-a205-460c-8371-8306895fcd8b|0101000020E610000091FF136DD8E63B40E5492DEF05E04740|industrial|brick    |
f9aabf00-c3aa-4a45-8c15-5b538390b807|0101000020E6100000E2395B4068E53B403A98A839D4E04740|industrial|brick    |
a866e708-6438-4524-b257-e3f7f84b7027|0101000020E610000077B6ECB545E63B400B067C235FE04740|industrial|brick    |
849add05-4384-492a-baf9-5d151751e8c5|0101000020E61000002B78C02B38E83B4098512CB7B4E04740|industrial|brick    |
ae8d7de0-10d1-4cf5-b4ef-7c483e9f6669|0101000020E61000009D9E776341E73B40A3923A014DE04740|industrial|brick    |
c3a908d7-49d1-4f95-a5d2-b9aa06a44768|0101000020E61000001E0B1BAF8AE53B403BE702F280E04740|industrial|brick    |
d86c441c-fcea-4b53-883e-e7651f8f7afd|0101000020E6100000EDA7B51FDFE43B403999B85510E04740|industrial|brick    |
d66543a3-f6a9-47dc-b47d-2e027b62d24d|0101000020E6100000A15F00868AE63B40113A43CC80E04740|industrial|brick    |
6d0ca88e-b645-4880-ad9a-a12dee11cb9c|0101000020E61000007E5704FF5BE53B403C9FA63BF4DF4740|industrial|brick    |
acf63b3f-d86c-478a-9267-97407103b490|0101000020E6100000ACADD85F76E53B40C0D02346CFE04740|industrial|brick    |
381995fe-c6ed-4916-a2a3-7def605ef30e|0101000020E6100000A02EF76E98E53B40267909A936E14740|industrial|brick    |
0279d9cc-0521-4c94-8132-2276f9dccb0f|0101000020E6100000383A9D1A1EE73B407F57BA7141E04740|industrial|brick    |
ec148677-783e-404a-9504-ac697dceb081|0101000020E6100000FBF14D89DAE43B40514942C7B3E04740|industrial|brick    |
680a6d28-34e5-4639-94df-32c00a9aceaf|0101000020E610000002678412C1E93B406353F87D49E14740|industrial|brick    |
a4f70282-c792-4ea0-b0af-cf7adea7904e|0101000020E6100000A651370653E93B40749593F540E14740|industrial|brick    |
c3f88db7-9b3c-44e8-b302-d45458389154|0101000020E610000041295AB917E83B40A4D1D336B4DF4740|industrial|brick    |
56021f76-f3df-4275-8c65-f1ad50053037|0101000020E610000057E47C563EE63B40FCD52D4CF0DF4740|industrial|brick    |
e2a1265a-6aa2-4b84-a5b6-b66868f7ba5d|0101000020E6100000330285D5B3E93B403E7B2E5393E04740|industrial|brick    |
bc423d77-ea20-4883-9b4f-60b3fc85961a|0101000020E61000005F07CE1951E43B40338573B279E04740|industrial|brick    |
62e982c2-3119-4962-81b3-219c0b43a02c|0101000020E6100000D322916C64E53B40CD4B0F54D7DF4740|industrial|brick    |
ad728221-d528-4856-bff8-80a5ac48956a|0101000020E610000061342BDB87E43B401C78B5DC99DF4740|industrial|brick    |
bd5cf4bd-2ba8-4404-9aee-923e9f9dbcc9|0101000020E6100000980BA6AB85E53B402134CC1A06E04740|industrial|brick    |
db981d6e-39a7-4fd9-8526-dcdbe9c2287a|0101000020E610000095DCBCCC0BE53B40F6FC7ACF92DF4740|industrial|brick    |
e7a9863c-0599-45ba-a0de-fd55636cb981|0101000020E6100000FD5E549CB4E43B4050D37833B4DF4740|industrial|brick    |
c6bd0ab2-33fe-4c10-9630-4dba1519aac0|0101000020E610000036EA211ADDE73B40139ED0EB4FE04740|industrial|brick    |
bd78f7ce-ff80-43b0-94a5-7c0d53c88e72|0101000020E61000000220387870E73B40C003A84EACE04740|industrial|brick    |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WKB` is just the representation of the processed points by Postgres. It's actually good! Imagine that you stored all these points as text, then how would you perform calculations on them, like clustering or calculating the distances between them?

To get their values in the way you want, just use

```sql
SELECT uuid, ST_ASTEXT(coordinate) as coordinate_wkt
FROM building
```

Comment: Note that PostGIS doesn't store the data as WKB internally. That is just the textual representation (what the data type output function produces). I know it sounds odd to have WKB as a *textual* representation, but that*s the way it is.